# How can I more efficiently perform a query that returns how many times an ID appears in two other tables?

Tags: sql, derby

I have found some solutions to this from other sources but none of them seem to be executing efficiently for me. I am using derby and my current solution is taking over a minute to execute!

I am trying to find the number of songs and albums that belong to a given artist and display those numbers in 2 separate columns next to the artist's name and id. ex:

```
ID    Name        Songs    Albums
425   J. Smith    0        0
314   A. Payne    32       3
412   K. Thomas   423      35
```

The artist table has artist_id, the song table has song_id and album_id, and the album table has album_id and artist_id. The tables aren't tiny. Artist has about 1,100 records, song has about 73,000, and album has about 7,000.

Here is my current solution:

```
select ar.artist_id, ar.artist_name, count(s.song_id), count(distinct(al.album_id))
from artist ar left outer join 
    (album al inner join song s 
    on al.album_id = s.album_id)
on ar.artist_id = al.artist_id 
group by ar.artist_id, ar.artist_name
```

Is there a way to make this query perform better? The ID columns are all primary keys in their respective tables, so they should already by indexed in derby if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses derived tables to get the song and album counts

```
select ar.artist_id, ar.artist_name, 
    coalesce(t1.song_cnt,0), coalesce(t2.album_cnt,0)
from artist ar left join (
    select artist_id, count(*) song_cnt
    from song group by artist_id
) t1 on t1.artist_id = ar.artist_id 
left join (
   select artist_id, count(*) album_cnt
   from album group by artist_id
) t2 on t2.artist_id = ar.artist_id
```

You might want to look into storing the counts themselves in your db and updating them using triggers.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I went from executing the query in around 90 seconds to under 0.3 seconds. I will also look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it in a single query, I think you'd be better of using subqueries and joining on those. Alternately you could work on breaking it up into a few small queries and let your application do the join instead of MySQL... it would definitely be A LOT faster to do small queries and then loop through the results to construct your output than the recursive inner joins you have going on.

(SELECT artist_id, COUNT(id) AS numAlbums FROM album GROUP BY artist_id)
(SELECT album_id, COUNT(id) AS numSongs FROM song GROUP BY album_id)

Lastly... I want to throw out that although when you are first using database design they talk about normalization like it is the law. But then when you get a little further along in your career you actually learn about denormalization and that sometimes pre-calculated columns (such as your counts) are acceptable and necessary for fast performance.